# Parse XML into DataTable

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I have the following XML:

```
<RECORDS>
  <RECORD>
    <PROPERTY NAME="FNAME" TYPE="string"></PROPERTY>
    <PROPERTY NAME="LNAME" TYPE="string">
      <VALUE>SMITH</VALUE>
    </PROPERTY>
    <PROPERTY NAME="ZIP" TYPE="string">
      <VALUE></VALUE>
    </PROPERTY>
    <PROPERTY NAME="PHONE" TYPE="string">
      <VALUE>5551212</VALUE>
    </PROPERTY>
  </RECORD>
  <RECORD>
     ....
  </RECORD>
  <RECORD>
     ....
  </RECORD>
  <RECORD>
     ....
  </RECORD>
</RECORDS>
```

There may be 1000 "RECORD" nodes under "RECORDS".   I am trying to simply dump each record into a data row (or the entire thing into a datatable).  I'd be happy to just get all the "VALUE"s into each row's column.   Is there an efficient way to do this in C#?  Doing a foreach() and accessing each property one at a time seems awfully slow.

I imagine it would involve Row.ItemArray or maybe XMLArray or something along those lines.

Interested to see a good solution to this!

Comment: If you want to go the DataSet route, try : var dataSet = new DataSet();            dataSet.ReadXml(xmlVariable);

Comment: What is "awfully slow"? You fundamentally have to iterate over each record to convert it from XML to a data row, so the `foreach` certainly isn't the problem in and of itself.

Comment: Using ReadXML might work but I am not clear on how to tell it the structure.  If you note, the column names are an attribute of Property and the value is the InnerText of VALUE (if it exists).

Comment: "Awfully slow" ... It can take 20-30 seconds to parse 800 records doing a foreach(record) then nest foreach(property).   800 records with 20 properties=16000 steps (at least).

Comment: If you could let me know what is your end goal, I think I will be able to help. Because if it is like fetching the values for certain nodes based on some criteria, even putting the whole XML in database and getting values back will not take much time. Also, if your end goal is to display this data on a page eventually, you might not need to write too many loops as that can be done using XSLT also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xml =
                "<RECORDS>" +
                  "<RECORD>" +
                    "<PROPERTY NAME=\"FNAME\" TYPE=\"string\"></PROPERTY>" +
                    "<PROPERTY NAME=\"LNAME\" TYPE=\"string\">" +
                      "<VALUE>SMITH</VALUE>" +
                    "</PROPERTY>" +
                    "<PROPERTY NAME=\"ZIP\" TYPE=\"string\">" +
                      "<VALUE></VALUE>" +
                    "</PROPERTY>" +
                    "<PROPERTY NAME=\"PHONE\" TYPE=\"string\">" +
                      "<VALUE>5551212</VALUE>" +
                    "</PROPERTY>" +
                  "</RECORD>" +
              "</RECORDS>";

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            List<XElement> properties = doc.Descendants("PROPERTY").ToList();

            //add columns to table
            foreach (XElement property in properties)
            {
                string name = property.Attribute("NAME").Value;
                string _type = property.Attribute("TYPE").Value;
                if(!dt.Columns.Contains(name))
                {
                    dt.Columns.Add(name, Type.GetType("System." + _type, false, true));
                }
            }

            //add rows to table
            foreach(XElement record in doc.Descendants("RECORDS").ToList())
            {
                DataRow newRow = dt.Rows.Add();
                foreach (XElement property in properties)
                {
                    string name = property.Attribute("NAME").Value;
                    Type  _type  = Type.GetType("System." + property.Attribute("TYPE").Value, false, true);
                    string value = property.Value;

                    switch (_type.ToString())
                    {
                        case "System.String" :
                            newRow[name] = (string)value;
                            break;
                        case "System.Int" :
                            newRow[name] = int.Parse(value);
                            break;
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```